# how do i hide the grand total from in tabular model's measurement using dax?

Tags: dax, tabular

I am using DAX to make a formula in the tabular model, but how can i hide the grand total part of that measure? i see grand total part whenever i open the pivot table and put the measurements. However i would like to hide the grand total part. How can i do that? Do i have to use dax formula for it, or do i have to set up in the tabular model?

```
12 Local:=CALCULATE (
    [Local],
    DATESINPERIOD(
        Calendar[Date] ,
        MAX ( Calendar[Date] ),
        -12,
        MONTH
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn off grand totals in the pivot table. Even if you write a measure that returns blank at the grand total level, you would just see a grand total line with nothing in it but the label.

[Totals in pivots.](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/Show-or-hide-subtotals-and-totals-in-a-PivotTable-fc4d8406-f230-4762-aa2f-310826f3e5e2)

Comment: thank you for helping me again! but what if i want to hide som of the lower hierarchies total?Usually higher hierarchy contains sum of lower hierarchies

Comment: You can selectively turn off subtotals for individual levels of the hierarchy. Again, writing a measure that would return blank would not remove the subtotal row, only display a blank value for the subtotal row. [Here's a link showing how to control subtotals at various levels](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-subtotals.html).

Comment: Thank you again.yeah that's what i meant i would like to show blank in subtotal row using dax. How can i do that?

Comment: You'll need to wrap your normal measure in some sort of IF() wrapper. It will entirely depend on your use case and desired edge case behavior, but the two most common constructions are IF(ISFILTERED()) and IF(HASONEVALUE()).

[Some](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/clever-hierarchy-handling-in-dax/) useful [reading](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/03/hasonevalue-vs-isfiltered-vs-hasonefilter/) for [you](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/03/isfiltered-a-better-way-to-detect-totals/).

Comment: Thanks! that is what i looking for